# Does one say "Tzidkatcha" and "El Maleh" next Shabbat (or any 28 Elul that falls on Shabbat)?

Tags: shabbat, rosh-hashanah-new-year, tachanun

ArtScroll and Birnbaum (Nusach Ashkenaz) siddurim state that *tzidkatcha* should not be said on a day when *Tachanun* would have been skipped had it been a weekday. I believe that similar instructions are indicated regarding saying "El Maleh" for someone's *yahrtzeit*.

On the rules for *Tachnaun*, these siddurim indicate that it is not said during Mincha on the day before such occasions.

My question, and confusion regarding the 2nd rule about "day before" aka *Erev*...

One of the days to omit *Tachanun* is Erev Rosh Hashanna, and Tachanun is not said during Shacharit either. Since the entire day of Erev Rosh Hashanna has no Tachanun, does that mean that the mincha of the day before that, which is "Erev Erev Rosh Hashanna" also omit tachanun, which, this year would translate to omitting both *tzikatcha* as well as *El Maleh*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Artscroll Yitzchak Yair *siddur* (the all-Hebrew *Ashkenaz* one) states that if 28 Elul is a weekday, *tachanun* is said even by *Mincha*, and on Shabbat, *tzikatcha* is said.

You are correct that normally, if *tachanun* is not said by *Shacharit*, it is omitted the previous afternoon as well. However, Erev Rosh Hashanah and Erev Yom Kippur (and perhaps Pesach Sheni) are exceptions.

I don't remember off-hand about *El Maleh*.

Comment: Interesting that they list this as an exception. I'll see if I can compare this with the *Ezras Torah* Luach. I would have thought that this follows the rules as every other holiday, but apparently, not.